# PHPStorm Live Templates: как использовать функцию «classNameComplete()»?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Для эксперимента, я просто создал шаблон, содержащий только одну переменную `$TEST$`, для которой задал функцию `classNameComplete()` в качестве выражения:

[image: PHPStorm Live Templates - $TEST$]

[image: PHPStorm Live Templates - TEST = classNameComplete()]

После зашёл в метод класса и раскрыл шаблон ожидая увидеть имя текущего класса, но его там не оказалось ...

Как используют эту функцию?

Comment: име текущего класса не `${NAME}` случаем или `${CLASS_NAME}`?

Comment: @Naumov, я не понял о чём вы?.. Я просто открываю любой попавшийся класс, тыкаю в пустое место, раскрываю указанный шаблон и ожидаю увидеть имя класса. Скорее я неверно интерпретирую использовании данной функции (собственно, поэтому и задал вопрос :)).

Comment: Напишите где в настройках он создаёться?

Comment: @Naumov, `(Ctrl+Alt+S или File->Settings..)->Editor->Live Templates`.

Answer (score 1):

Пишу ответом, так как комментарии не позваляют форматировать цитаты в общем из документации

> This expression substitutes for the class name completion at the
>   variable position.

источник https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/10.0/live-template-variables.html#d458733e131

в свободном переводе это будет так

> Это условие используется для автодополнения имени класса в позиции этой
>   переменной

т.е. всё так и есть в место переменой `$TEST$` вы получаете место где phpStorm будет выводить подсказку автодополнения класса.

p.s. Давайте разберёмся в том что вы хотите и как это можно реализовать.

не везде к примеру `/**  */` в нутри коментария не будет, по идее должен автокоплит сработать если так написать `/** $className */` но нет не работает... https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16721 есть к стати баг по этому поводу.

Comment: Это я и читаю как раз, только последнюю [версию](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/edit-template-variables-dialog.html#predefined_functions) ... PHPStrom и так везде подсказки выводит, зачем она (`classNameComplete()`) тогда в шаблонах?..

Comment: @RomanGrinyov отредактировал вопрос. Как у вас формируеться име класса по какому стандарту?

Comment: Я пробовал в Yii2 и просто в чистом файлике с классом аля `class A {...}` писать — ничего не подставляется в обоих случаях.

Comment: в yii2 есть стандарт можно име класса сформировать допустим из имени файла. @RomanGrinyov

Comment: Это понятно, просто хотелось бы узнать где эта функция используется раз она есть.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov так это понятно к примеру 8 шторм не умел подсвечивать такие вещи `/** @var ClassName $test */` где ClassNam e то что он подсвечивает сейчас, а тогда наверное можно было решить live template.